# Is there a git personal server for sharing changes between machines?

Tags: git

Is there a way to run a no frills git server just so I work on different machines at home?

The main reason for this is that my WiFi network is slow and I'd prefer to work locally and disconnected.

I assume there's something similar to the Mercurial command **hg serve**.

Comment: Do you *need* a "server"? A shared file system or an SSH connection between the hosts should suffice.

Comment: I understand that. But can't you use your existing setup with either simple file sharing (NFS, CIFS, ...) or SSH?

Comment: I have a laptop that I work on as well as a desktop over wifi. It's much faster if I work locally than simply using a file share.

Comment: This is a bit of an [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341)…

Comment: @Johnsyweb - Please explain professor

Comment: Your *question* is: "Is there a git personal server for sharing changes between machines?" Your *problem* is that you want to `fetch` a repository from your desktop to your laptop. You don't *need* a "git personal server" for this. You can simply `fetch` from a file share or via SSH.

Comment: Do you mean just performing a normal file copy over the network?

Comment: Not quite. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544961/is-there-a-git-personal-server-for-sharing-changes-between-machines/7592277#7592277)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a minimalist `git daemon` server. (See [here](http://book.git-scm.com/4_setting_up_a_public_repository.html) for basic info, and the man page for more.)

Answer (score 4):

A good guide to the different methods is http://www.jedi.be/blog/2009/05/06/8-ways-to-share-your-git-repository/

My preferred method is to use the plain ssh server.

Answer (score 2):

the easiest way is just to share disks/directories using the stand OS file sharing.

Otherwise you can run a git server `git-daemon` or export via http see Git documentation for [public repository](http://schacon.github.com/git/user-manual.html#public-repositories)

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments, this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56366/147331).

[Mat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544961/is-there-a-git-personal-server-for-sharing-changes-between-machines/7544995#7544995) tells you about a minimalist git daemon server. As do others.

I'm telling you that this is probably entirely unnecessary.

If your laptop and your desktop can share a filesystem (such as via NFS, CIFS or similar), you can [`clone`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-clone.html) the repository like this:

```
git clone /path/to/repository
```

If your laptop and your desktop can't share a filesystem but your desktop is running an SSH service, you can clone your repository like this:

```
git clone ssh://[user@]server/path/to/repository
```

You may even be able to use other sharing services such as FTP or HTTP, as per the [manual page](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-clone.html). Setting up a dedicated git server is usually an unnecessary overhead.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry I had no idea it was possible to use SSH in that way. I do have a SSH server running and will give this a go. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am using gitolite, I find it easy enough.

Here is the [Official documentation](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite#start) and [my experience](http://www.stefanolocati.it/blog/?p=1018).